# For Loop to count checked items on datagrid not counting correctly

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I worked out the following loop to count and display how many rows on my datagrid are checked. However, the loop is ignoring my first checked row. The count does not start at 1 until I have checked the second row. The same happens when I uncheck, the values are off by one.

```
Dim chkRowCount As Integer = 0
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvAssignGridView.Rows 
    If row.Cells(6).Value = True Then               
        chkRowCount += 1            
    Else                
        chkRowCount += 0            
    End If        
Next       
lblChkCount.Text = chkRowCount.ToString
```

I have tried setting the variable to 1 instead of 0, but that had some unwanted results.

Comment: Besides the fact that the `chkRowCount += 0` line is wildly unnecessary, I don't see anything wrong with the logic.  So... are you sure that `dgvAssignGridView` is the right grid?  Are you sure `Cells(6)` is the right column?  Are you sure `lblChkCount` is the right label?

Comment: set a breakpoint on `If row.Cells(6)...` and see if the value is what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have this code in CellContentClick.  The problem is that the code in that routine fires before the value of the checkbox is actually changed.  However, you can basically force the DataGridView to verify itself first by putting the following line right before your code.

```
dgvAssignGridView.EndEdit()
```

That forces the cell click to register before you do your count.